# webpage insert multiple data into database

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, dreamweaver

I am writing a Php (or rather using dreamweaver to easily so it) to insert multiple data into a database. For example if I have 10 values, instead of submitting each one individually, is it just possible to copy and paste the 10 values separated by a space so that they go into different rows. For learning purposes, I have done a simple page, connected to a Phpmyadmin database named cmsd1. Code as of now is

```
<?php require_once('Connections/cmsdtest.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cmsd1 (Population_Name) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Form1'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_cmsdtest, $cmsdtest);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $cmsdtest) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "ttt.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_cmsdtest, $cmsdtest);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT Population_Name FROM cmsd1";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $cmsdtest) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
Population
  <label for="Form1"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Form1" id="Form1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

It goes to a simple webpage to just deposit data.

[image: Simple website to insert values]

Please don't go into detailed code since I am not very good at PhP coding.. Thanks for any help offered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert multiple rows you do the following:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6);
```

This will insert two rows where row one has `1`, `2`, and `3` for columns `a`, `b`, and `c` and row two has `4`, `5`, and `6`.

See the documentation on [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) statements.

To have this work with posted values where you have a single field with space-separated values you would do something like the following:

```
$values = explode(' ', $_POST['values']);

foreach ($values as &$value)
{
  $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_name (a) VALUES ('" . implode("'), ('", $values) . "')");
```

Although I would advise that you look into using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) and get away from the `mysql` extension which is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`. Try [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I am sorry but I do know that it is possible in SQL. I am trying to submit multiple data through a textfield on a webpage here. So not what I am looking for.